# Javascript: Dates in month and date is resetting everytime the user change the year

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm almost wanted to give up for my date picker codes lol. Is there any example there for date picker with 3 dropdowns that is working properly and perfect. I got stock for 2 days and I think my date picker codes is not working as I expected. All is working fine now except that it resets the value of month and date I already selected when I changed the year.

For example:
I choose `year --> 1990 month -->02  date -->22`

then when I change into another year the value of month and date is reset and become 1 which should not:

`year --> 1991 month -->1  date -->1`

What I wanted is even when I change in another year or month the dropdowns will not reset or become 1. Should I recode it :-(. Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
function daysInMonth(m, y){
               return m===2?y&3||!(y%25)&&y&15?28:29:30+(m+(m>>3)&1);
            }

            var monthArray = []; 
            var dateArray = []; 
            function onYearChange() {
                monthArray =[];
                var year = document.getElementById("yeardialog").value
                    if (document.getElementById("yeardialog").value != "0"){
                        for(var i = 1 ; i<=12; i++){
                        monthArray.push(i + '');
                        dateArray.push(daysInMonth(i, year));
                    }

                var select = document.getElementById("monthdialog");
                    select.innerHTML = "";
                        for(var i = 0; i < monthArray.length; i++) {
                            var monthOptions = monthArray[i].replace('', '');
                            var el = document.createElement("option");
                                el.textContent = monthOptions + '';

                            if(monthOptions<10){
                                monthOptions = '0'+monthOptions
                            }
                                el.value = monthOptions;
                                select.appendChild(el);
                        }
                      onMonthChange();
              console.log(monthArray);
       }   
      }

            function onMonthChange(){ 
                if(dateArray.length>12){
                    dateArray.splice(0, 12);
                }
                var dates =[]; 
                var month = document.getElementById("monthdialog").value;
                var endDay = dateArray[month.replace('', '')-1];

                for(var date = 1; date<=endDay; date++){
                    dates.push(date + '');
                }

                var select = document.getElementById("datedialog");
                select.innerHTML = "";

                for(var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
                    var dateOptions = dates[i].replace('', '');
                    var el = document.createElement("option");
                        el.textContent = dateOptions + '';

                    if(dateOptions<10){
                        dateOptions = '0'+dateOptions
                    }
                    el.value = dateOptions;
                    select.appendChild(el);
                }
            }
```

```html
<select id="yeardialog" name="yeardialog" onchange="onYearChange()">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="1990">1990</option>
  <option value="1991">1991</option>
  <option value="1992">1992</option>

</select>
<select id="monthdialog" onchange="onMonthChange()">
  <option></option>
</select>

<select id="datedialog">
  <option></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Whenever you change the list of options in a select list you'll need to reset the selected value.

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from the fact you're recreating the month list when you change the year which changes the day list. You could re-write the whole thing to not do this or you could store the currently selected values before you recreate the list and select it again after the list has been created.

I would say though that all years have the same number of months so it's not really useful to dynamically generate it. The only list you're actually interested in changing is the day list so you can write it so that changing the year or month selection just alters the available days (saving the previously selected value and reselecting it if it's valid if you like)

Comment: I have the same problem. Is there any solution? An easy to implement one? :)